# ASP.NET: Get *real* raw URL

Tags: asp.net, url, url-encoding, rawurl

In ASP.NET, is there any way to get the *real* raw URL?

For example, if a user browse to "http://example.com/mypage.aspx/%2F", I would like to be able to get "http://example.com/mypage.aspx/%2F" rather than "http://example.com/mypage.aspx//".

I would of course like a clean way to do it, but I can live with a hacky approach using reflection or accessing obscure properties.

At the moment, I try to use the uri in the Authorization-header (which works), but I cannot rely on that always being there.

**EDIT:**

What I really want to do is to be able to distinguish between "http://example.com/mypage.aspx/%2F" and "http://example.com/mypage.aspx/%2F%2F".

It looks like ASP.NET first converts "%2F%2F" into "//" and then converts the slashes into a single slash.

So just re-encoding it is not going to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)HttpContext.Current;
HttpWorkerRequest workerRequest = (HttpWorkerRequest)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));
string realUrl = workerRequest.GetServerVariable("HTTP_URL");
```

Note that this only works when running on the IIS and not under f.x. ASP.NET Development Server!

Thanks to [Lucero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757806/get-the-exact-url-the-user-typed-into-the-browser/757813#757813) for the answer in another thread and [Zhaph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781596/asp-net-get-real-raw-url/782165#782165) for pointing me to the thread.

Comment: This is the right solution. It addresses issues when there is encoding in the path. The HTTP_URL from server variables will display the decoded version and this solution provides the correct encoded version.

Comment: This returns the expected result under IIS Express as well

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't able to test this because it only works in IIS and not the ASP.NET Development Server that is part of Visual Studio, but try:

Request.ServerVariables[ "HTTP_URL" ]

Comment: This returns the expected result for me, though it does need combining with HTTP_HOST and HTTP_QUERY to get the rest of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

See also:

> [Get the exact url the user typed into the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757806/get-the-exact-url-the-user-typed-into-the-browser)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Server.HtmlEncode(Request.RawUrl);
```

The raw URL is defined as the part of the URL following the domain information. In the URL string http://www.contoso.com/articles/recent.aspx, the raw URL is /articles/recent.aspx. The raw URL includes the query string, if present.

see also:[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx)

Comment: Any URLs in Request are potentially already cleaned, Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"] is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test here, but this might be what you need:

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

Answer (score 1):

`Request.RawUrl` will return the application relative path(including querystring info) while `Request.Url` will return the complete path(including querystring info).

For more information, see "[Making sense of ASP.NET paths](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths)".

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just encode it back to the url-encoded version.

Answer (score 0):

Get the url from the request and urlencode only the query string part and then concatenate them