# How do I get the un-decoded request URL under ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, uri, rawurl

My request URL is: http://domain.com/some/path%2Fescaped.

I want to retrieve this exact URL. I do NOT want it decoded, like http://domain.com/some/path/escaped; I want it encoded like http://domain.com/some/path%2Fescaped.

**How do I get this URL?** I have tried Request.Path, Request.RawUrl, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, Request.Url.OriginalString...each provide the URL decoded, like http://domain.com/some/path/escaped.

I can get this in PHP with $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].

Comment: Have a look at this thread.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781596/asp-net-get-real-raw-url

Comment: Doesn't have the answer. I'm not always using IIS.

Comment: try Server.URLEncode. but it will encode all special characters in URL

Comment: Unfortunately Server.UrlEncode encodes path separators as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Request.Url.OriginalString;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to work or not, but have you already tried `Server.URLDecode` or `Server.URLEncode`?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a non-solution, as this encodes the entire URL, subsequently encoding all instances of "/", including actual path separators.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript call document.location.href should return the expected format. Here is a suggestion; Check if this works for you.

1) have a hidden variable

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdn" runat="server" />
```

2) Set hidden variable using javascript function

```
function setURL() {
        document.getElementById("hdn").value = document.location.href;
    }
```

3) on server side

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
        "setURL", "setURL();", true);
```

4) read hidden variable value at server side (which is the URL in actual format)

```
hdn.Value
```