# Retrieve the Original (Client) Url Without the Default Document

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to obtain the actual client requested URL. The standard `Request.Url` object contains the response URL. These can be different if the original request did not contain a default document.

Original Request: http://my.server.com/folder/

Request.Url.ToString(): http://my.server.com/folder/default.aspx

Is there a way to obtain the original client request in asp.net?

Comment: Hmm this appears to have been asked before, even though I searched for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757806/get-the-exact-url-the-user-typed-into-the-browser